# scrollViewDidScroll crash when calling self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11

I have this method

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView is GLIndexedCollectionView { return }

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 120 && self.navBarHidden == true {
        self.navBarHidden = false
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

        self.topTvConstraint.constant = 44.0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.navigationBarConstraint.constant = 65

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        var scrollBounds = self.tv.bounds
        scrollBounds.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 185)
        self.tv.bounds = scrollBounds

    }
}
```

The idea is to animated a top bar and change the status bar color, so I use setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate to

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if navBarHidden {
        return .lightContent
    }

    return .default 
}
```

but.... if I compile in Xcode 9 and run it in a real device or simulator with iOS 11 it crash in this line

```
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

and if I try iOS 10.3 works as expected, why?? any help please!

[image]

Comment: you have to check device version for call this method

Comment: but the method is not deprecated in iOS11, isn't?

Comment: check my answer this working for me in project so i share it with you

Answer (score 2):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()
} else {
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

note: This is a small but significant change in iOS 11. If you rely on hiding the status bar to use gestures at the screen edges you should update your app and override `setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` for iOS 11.

Comment: so this is the new way to force a re evaluation of override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle???

now, I know this other piece of code but is part of the same block
crash here!!
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

what is going on?? where di u get this info? btw thanks for help

Comment: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/avoiding-conflicts-with-system-gestures-at-screen-edges/ from here @goseta